# ion-tab content is overlapped by nav bar and tab bar

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to get tabs working but no matter what I try I can't get tab content to show below the tab bar. Here is my view:

```
<ion-view title="My Bookings">
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-color-positive tabs-striped">
    <ion-tab title="Current Booking" ui-sref="bookings/current">
      <ion-list class="bookings has-header has-tabs-top">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="booking in bookings">
          <div class="info">
            <p class="name">{{booking.name}}</p>
            <p class="date">{{booking.date}}</p>
            <p class="time">{{booking.time}}</p>
          </div>
          <button class="cancel-button">Cancel Booking</button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Past Booking" ui-sref="bookings/past"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-view
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried using `has-header` and `has-tabs-top` on everything but it didn't help.

Note: I've configured tabs to be always on top like this (as per Ionic docs):

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('top');
})
```

I'm using Ionic 1.3.1.

**Edit**

This is what I have after Sam5487's answer:

```
.state('bookings', {
  url: '/bookings',
  templateUrl: 'templates/bookings/bookings.html'
})
.state('bookings.current', {
  url: '/bookings/current',
  templateUrl: 'templates/bookings/current_bookings.html',
  controller: 'CurrentBookingsController'
})
.state('bookings.past', {
  url: '/bookings/past',
  templateUrl: 'templates/bookings/past_bookings.html',
  controller: 'PastBookingsController'
})
```

bookings.html:

```
<ion-view title="My Bookings">
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-tabs id="bookings-view" class="bookings-view tabs-color-positive tabs-striped">
    <ion-tab title="Current Booking" ui-sref="bookings.current">
      <ion-nav-view name="currentBookings"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Past Booking" ui-sref="bookings.past">
      <ion-nav-view name="pastBookings"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

current_bookings.html:

```
<ion-view title="Current Bookings">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list class="bookings">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="booking in bookings">
        <div class="info">
          <p class="name">{{booking.name}}</p>
          <p class="date">{{booking.date}}</p>
          <p class="time">{{booking.time}}</p>
        </div>
        <button class="cancel-button">Cancel Booking</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

However, tab content is empty for some reason :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not wrapping with `<ion-content></ion-content>` at all in your code, and the structuring could be better, do so like below.

```
<body>

    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-color-positive tabs-striped">
        <ion-tab title="Current Booking" ui-sref="bookings/current">
            <ion-nav-view name="currentBooking">
             <ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
             </ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-view title="My Bookings">
                    <ion-content>
                        <ion-list>
                            <ion-item ng-repeat="booking in bookings">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <p class="name">{{booking.name}}</p>
                                    <p class="date">{{booking.date}}</p>
                                    <p class="time">{{booking.time}}</p>
                                </div>
                                <button class="cancel-button">Cancel Booking</button>
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-list>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-view>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Past Booking" ui-sref="bookings/past"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>

</body>
```

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNYRmr) (note: didn't add mock data, but you can see there is no overlapping with hardcoded text. Add mock data in the JS to see for yourself).

**However, I would suggest strucuting your project differently.**

```
->www
   ->css 
   ->js  (controllers.js, services.js, directives.js, routes.js, app.js)
   ->lib (external libs)
   ->plugins
   ->tempaltes
      ->tabs.html
      ->currentBookings.html
      ->pastBookings.html
```

`tabs.html` will consist of your tabs tmeplate only, so when you add more it is quite easy (I add back buttons for each tab since they each have their own stack history), exmaple:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-color-positive tabs-striped">
        <ion-tab title="Current Booking" ui-sref="bookings/current">
            <ion-nav-view name="currentBookings">
              <ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
              </ion-nav-bar>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Past Booking" ui-sref="bookings/past">
            <ion-nav-view name="pastBookings">
              <ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
                </ion-nav-bar>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        .
        .
</ion-tabs>
```

Your current bookings page will look like this: `currentBookings.html`

```
<ion-view title="My Bookings">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list class="bookings">
            <ion-item>
                <div ng-repeat="booking in bookings"">
                    <p class="name">{{booking.name}}</p>
                    <p class="date">{{booking.date}}</p>
                    <p class="time">{{booking.time}}</p>
                </div>
                <button class="cancel-button">Cancel Booking</button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And for the other page: `pastBookings.html`

```
<ion-view title="Past Bookings">
    <ion-content>
        //Your content here.
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Take a look at the Ionic documentation on structuring, routing, and navigation [here](http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/10/understanding-router-in-ionic.html). It is *very* important to understand how views work.

**EDIT 2**

Your angular routing should look like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('bookings', {
    url: '/bookings',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/bookings/bookings.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('bookings.current', {
    url: '/current',
    views: {
      'currentBookings': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/bookings/current_bookings.html',
      }
    }
  })

  .state('bookings.past', {
    url: '/past',
    views: {
      'pastBookings': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/bookings/past_bookings.html',
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/bookings/current');

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Organizing tabs like you described actually solved the problem, I no longer have to set top offset for tab content. It's strange I didn't find this anywhere in the official docs, is this behavior described anywhere? I must be blind or something.

Comment: Well that was a little premature, it's not quite working yet: for some reason tab content isn't showing and I don't see any errors. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Is `<ion-nav-view name="currentBookings">` or whatever you named it matching up in your `stateProvider/urlProvider` config? Seems like its simply not rendering the `<ion-view>` child from `<ion-nav-view>` tab

Comment: I edited the routing, it works for me. Let me know if you have more issues

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ion-tab inside tag `<ion-nav-view>`:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <!-- The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate -->
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <!-- where the initial view template will be rendered -->
  <ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view>
      <ion-content>Hello!</ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm doing now, however tab content is empty for some reason. I updated the original question with some info. Do you know what might be causing that?